# SVG is not moving perfectly

Tags: html, css, svg

As you can see in the output my SVG `#square` is moving up but the shape stays still.
Why is this happening and How can i fix this?

```css
#square {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0%;
            left: -5%;
        }
        #square path:nth-child(2) {
            animation: sq 3s infinite ease;
        }
        @keyframes sq {
            from {
                transform: translateY(0);
            }
            to {
                transform: translateY(-20%);
            }
        }
```

```html
 <svg id="square" width="10%" viewBox="0 0 768 390" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M325.5 389.5L1 33V1H767L694.5 389.5H325.5Z" fill="#326F89"/>
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M0.5 0.5H767.602L694.915 390H325.279L0.5 33.1935V0.5ZM1.5 1.5V32.8065L325.721 389H694.085L766.398 1.5H1.5Z" fill="black"/>
            </svg>
```

Comment: This example is pretty difficult to see-- it might be helpful to make it bigger.  Also, can you clearly describe the _expected_ behavior, and how the _actual_ behavior in your snippet differs from what you want?

Comment: sure... The element ( teal colored ) isn't moving just the black border is moving. I want the square shape to move up to down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to move your entire svg element, apply the animation to it and not to the second child, who is the line ;)

```css
#square {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: -5%;
  animation: sq 3s infinite ease;
}
/*#square path:nth-child(2) {
  animation: sq 3s infinite ease;
}*/
@keyframes sq {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(-20%);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="square"  viewBox="0 0 768 390" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M325.5 389.5L1 33V1H767L694.5 389.5H325.5Z" fill="#326F89"/><!--background-->
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M0.5 0.5H767.602L694.915 390H325.279L0.5 33.1935V0.5ZM1.5 1.5V32.8065L325.721 389H694.085L766.398 1.5H1.5Z" fill="black"/> <!--line, who move-->
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks but i want this teal colored shaped to move up to down... here just the border is moving.

Comment: Is this better ?

Comment: Yeah.... Thanks and also thanks for the explanation it was a rookie mistake.